# Find angle of this polygon

Tags: geometry, angle

I apologize for this simple question but unfortunately I'm not  good at geometry.  Consider a polygon in the following image

we have
$$AB=BC=AD.$$ I want to find he angle $C$

How can I find the angle? Can anybody help me?  .[image]

Comment: Please mention what have you tried and where you stuck...

Comment: Spandan Kukade, I'm  sorry unfortunately I don't have any idea

Comment: just I know $\angle A+\angle B+\angle C+\angle D=360$

Comment: Doug M, I find $\angle ADB=53$

Comment: hint: reflect $A$ with respect to segment $BD$ to get $E$. what can you say about $\triangle BCE$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a second triangle that is congruent to $\triangle ABD$

[image]

Use what you know about isosceles triangles to find $\angle ABD, \angle DBA'$ and $\angle A'BC$

From this we find $\angle BA'C$ and $\angle A'CD$

Comment: (+1)Thank you for your time and for your help

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\bbox[lightgreen]{AB=BC=AD}$, $\implies$ $\triangle{ABD}$ is isosceles, $\implies$ $\angle{ABD}=\angle{ADB}=\frac{180^{0}-74^{0}}{2}=53^{0}$, $\implies$ $\angle{DBC}=113^{0}$.

Let to be $\bbox[lightblue]{a=AB=BC=AD}$.

---

Using the well very known **law of sines** relatively $\triangle{ADB}$ we can get that:
$$
\frac{DB}{\sin(74^{0})}=\frac{a}{\sin(53^{0})}\implies{DB}=\frac{a\cdot{\sin(74^{0})}}{\sin(53^{0})}.
$$

---

Using the well very known **law of cosines** relatively $\triangle{DBC}$ we can get that:
$$
DC^{2}=DB^{2}+BC^{2}-2\cdot{DB}\cdot{BC}\cdot\cos(\angle{DBC})=
$$
$$
=\frac{a^{2}\sin^{2}(74^{0})+a^{2}\sin^{2}(53^{0})-2a^{2}\sin(74^{0})\cos(113^{0})\sin(53^{0})}{\sin^{2}(53^{0})}=
$$
$$
=\frac{a^{2}(\sin^{2}(74^{0})+\sin^{2}(53^{0})-\sin(106^{0})\sin(74^{0}))}{\sin^{2}(53^{0})},\implies
\\
\implies{DC}=\frac{a}{\sin(53^{0})}\left(\sin^{2}(74^{0})+\sin^{2}(53^{0})-\sin(106^{0})\sin(74^{0})\right)^{0.5}.
$$

---

Using the well very known **law of sines** relatively $\triangle{DBC}$ we can get that:
$$
\frac{DB}{\sin(\angle{BCD})}=\frac{DC}{\sin(\angle{DBC})}\implies\sin(\angle{BCD})=\frac{DB\cdot\sin(\angle{DBC})}{DC}=
\\
=\frac{a\cdot\sin(74^{0})\sin(113^{0})\sin(53^{0})}{a\sin(53^{0})\left(\sin^{2}(74^{0})+\sin^{2}(53^{0})-\sin(106^{0})\sin(74^{0})\right)^{0.5}}.\implies
$$
$$
\implies
\bbox[pink]
{
\angle{BCD}=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(74^{0})\sin(113^{0})}{\left(\sin^{2}(74^{0})+\sin^{2}(53^{0})-\sin(106^{0})\sin(74^{0})\right)^{0.5}}\right).
}
$$

Good luck!

Comment: (+1)Thank you for your time and for your help

Comment: Vadim Chernetsov, I think there was something wrong in the law of cosines relatively you right

Comment: $\angle DBC=113$

Answer (score 1):

$ABD$ is an isosceles triangle   $→$  $\angle ABD= \angle ADB =53°$
Draw two circles centers at $A$ and $B$ with radius $AB=BC$
Triangle $ABE$ is an equilateral triangle $→$ $\angle BAE=60°$
Central angle $\angle BAE=60° → \angle BDE=30°$
In triangle $BCD$, the angle $\angle BCD=37°$
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and for your help

Answer (score 1):

Another answer:

Construct an equilateral triangle ADE.

By simple angle chasing you can find some angles in the picture below

Now you know that $AE=AB$ and $\angle EAC= \angle BAC=7$ degrees

Then you can find that ABCE is a rhombus

Then that all side lengths are equal.

You already know that $\angle AED=60, \angle AEC=166$ (Since ABCE is a rhombus)

Then you can find $\angle AEC$ as follows

$\angle AEC+60+166=360$

$\angle AEC=134$

Since $\triangle DEC$ is isosceles $\angle ECD=23$

Finally
$\angle BCD=23+7+7$

$\angle BCD=37$ degrees

[image]

Comment: (+1)Thank you for your time and for your help